# Why can't I go to other Controller rather than HomeController in Spring framework?

Tags: spring, request-mapping

I created a Spring project with STS, using MySql with MyBatis.

I'm trying to make a function for Members to Sign up, but it only keep visiting Homecontroller.java instead of MemberController, when I click the submit button.

This is the arrangement of my files and codes.

This is from index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>

<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>

<P>  The time on the server is ${serverTime}. </P>
<h1> This is the first page to Log In</h1>

<form id="form1" action="members/logIn">
    LogIn <p>
    ID: <input type="text" name="id" id="id">
    Password: <input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd">
    <input type="button" onclick="logIn()" value="press to LogIn">
</form>

<p><br><br><h3>Move to SignUp page</h3>
<input type="button" onclick="window.location='views/signUp.jsp'" value="Move to Sign Up page">

<h1> This is to Sign Up  </h1>
<form id="form2" action="members/join">
    ID:
    <input type="text"  placeholder="Insert ID">
    Name:
    <input type="text"  placeholder="Insert Name"> <p>
    PWD:
    <input type="text"  placeholder="Insert your PWD"> <p>
    PWD Check:
    <input type="text"  placeholder="Confirm your PWD"><p>
    Address:
    <input type="text"  placeholder="Insert Address.">  <p>

    <input type="submit" value="Sign Up">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

and HomeController.java

```
package kr.co.promptech.controller;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

/**
 * Handles requests for the application home page.
 */
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

    /**
     * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
        logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);

        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);

        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

        model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );

        System.out.println("Arrived at HomeController.");

        return "index";
    }
}
```

MemberController.java

```
package kr.co.promptech.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import kr.co.promptech.model.Members;
import kr.co.promptech.service.MemberService;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/members")
public class MemberController {

    @Autowired
    private MemberService memberService;

    @RequestMapping(value="join")
    public String memberJoin(@RequestParam("id") String id, @RequestParam("pwd") String pwd,
                            @RequestParam("name") String name, @RequestParam("address") String address){

        System.out.println("We have arrived at MemberController");

        memberService.memberJoin(new Members(id, pwd, name, address));

        return "main";
    }


}
```

Why the Sign Up button keep brings me to HomeController instead MemberController?

also, can anyone help me how to make a button that brings me to main.jsp from index.jsp?

this is not working...

Hope someone can help me here...

Comment: can you try url localhost:8080/promptech/members/join?id=test&pwd=test&name=test&address=test

Comment: While I try out your suggestions, I found out that the tags of index.jsp did not have any name properties. Sorry, and Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Jay.K why you rejected my edit? Do you even know, what I had changed?

Comment: Sorry, I just realized what I did after I hit the 'reject' button. I was signed up at this site for a while, but I'm still kinda new here. I'm not really understanding the system here. No meaning of ignoring you!

Answer (score 0):

OMG, I just found out that all the tags of index.jsp did not have name properties.

It was all my faults... sorry, and Thanks for your answer,